# typescript for / of generating invalid javascript

Tags: typescript

I am using typescript in visual studio 2015 in an ASP.NET web application.
(default typescript settings, version 1.8.36.0 - I always use `"use strict"` in my `.ts` files.)

Given the following code:

```
for (let file of element.files) {
    file.sourceDocumentId = id;
}
```

The `.js` file generated by typescript is as follows.

```
for (var _i = 0, _a = element.files; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
    var file = _a[_i];
    file.sourceDocumentId = id;
}
```

**Firefox throws an exception indicating that `_a` is undefined.**
this error seems reasonable - is this a bug in typescript?

Comment: It would help to know what are `element` and `element.files`

Comment: The code is valid, but `element` has no `files` property at runtime

Comment: @Gone Coding thanks, it was `element.dataTransfer.files`. I stared at it, but couldn't see it. It's now a stupid question, but I am very happy to accept an answer if you post it. We can let the community decide if my question is stupid enough to vote for deletion. I mistakenly thought the `_a` might be missing a `var` in front of it because of `"use strict"`.

Comment: Try source mapping, then you can debug your typescript directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment as answer:

The code is valid, but `element` has no `files` property at runtime...

`_a` is `undefined` because `element.files` really *is* `undefined`. :)